# Why is drawing my custom JComponent on existing JPanel showing nothing?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcomponent

I am trying to create a custom JComponent which will be a custom progress bar, however I cannot get it to show up on an existing JPanel (which does show up correctly), not sure what the issue is.

```
public class JCustomProgressBar extends JComponent{

private final Dimension SIZE = new Dimension( 120, 120 );

public JCustomProgressBar() {
    super();
    this.setVisible(true);
}

int progress = 50; // temporary keeps progress at 50% for now while I debug

public void updateProgress (int progress){
    this.progress = progress;
}

 @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return SIZE;
   }

 @Override
 public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
   //super.paintComponent(g);
   System.out.println("called");
   Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g.create();
   g2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
   g2D.translate(this.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight()/2);
   g2D.rotate(Math.toRadians(270));
   Arc2D.Float arc = new Arc2D.Float (Arc2D.PIE);
   Ellipse2D circle = new Ellipse2D.Float(0, 0, 110, 110);
   arc.setFrameFromCenter (new Point(0,0), new Point (120, 120));
   circle.setFrameFromCenter(new Point(0,0), new Point (110, 110));
   arc.setAngleExtent(progress*360/100);
   g2D.setColor(Color.green);
   g2D.draw(arc);
   g2D.fill(arc);

   g2D.setColor(Color.gray);
   g2D.draw(circle);
   g2D.fill(circle);

   g2D.setColor(Color.black);
   g2D.rotate(Math.toRadians(90));
   g2D.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 50));
   FontMetrics fm = g2D.getFontMetrics();
   Rectangle2D r = fm.getStringBounds(progress + "%", g);
   int x = (0 - (int) r.getWidth())/2;
   int y = (0 - (int) r.getHeight())/2 +fm.getAscent();
   g2D.drawString(progress + "%", x, y);
   g2D.dispose();
}
```

### Edit

I am calling my draw method on a button click, as so (works perfectly and draws my JPanel properly).

```
/**Called when a button created using createButton() is clicked. This method 
should return true if it handled the click event, and false if the click 
should be passed on to the parent.

Overrides: onButtonClick(...) in GuiScreen*/


@Override
protected boolean onButtonClick(String id) {

    if(id.equals("btnIDConfirmL")) {
        drawLeftFillProgressBar();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Inside my draw method I add the JPanel to my parent JPanel, give it bounds, a color and a border. It shows up on the screen properly and all is well at this point, but when I try to add the JComponent I made, it never shows up on the screen. I can add another JPanel to the one I make here no problem, I can add a JLabel as well no problem for some reason just my JComponent wont show up.

```
    private JComponent customProgressBarL;
    private JPanel backgroundPanel;

private void drawLeftFillProgressBar(){
    leftFillProgressJPanel = createPanel(this.backgroundPanel, new Rectangle(0,backgroundPanel.getHeight()/2 - (this.getPanel().getWidth()/3 - 2*10)/2, this.getPanel().getWidth()/3 - 2*10, this.getPanel().getWidth()/3 + 87));
    leftFillProgressJPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
    leftFillProgressJPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));

    customProgressBarL = new JCustomProgressBar();
    leftFillProgressJPanel.add(customProgressBarL);
    customProgressBarL.setVisible(true);
    customProgressBarL.validate();

}
```

My createPanel method is located inside my GuiScreen class and looks like this:

```
protected JPanel createPanel(JComponent parent, Rectangle bounds){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);

    if(bounds != null){
        panel.setBounds(bounds);
    }
    if(parent != null){
        parent.add(panel);
    }

    return panel;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The problem is likely to be in the way you add the component to your layout. Post mcve as advised.

Comment: Works fine for me. I just added the component directly to the frame. This is the easiest way to test a new component so you know the problem isn't related to a layout manager since the component will be sized to fit the entire space of the frame. Once that woks, then you add it to a panel that will respect the preferred size of the component to make sure that works correctly. In any case,  the problem is definitely how you add the component to your panel.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted the solution on behalf of the question author)*.

I solved this by adding the following to my draw method: turns out I had to specify bounds using the setBounds method so that the bounds encompassed my entire JComponent after I added it to my parent JPanel.

```
    customProgressBarL = new JCustomProgressBar();
    leftFillProgressJPanel.add(customProgressBarL);

    int width = 190;
    int height = 290;

    customProgressBarL.setBounds(new Rectangle(leftFillProgressJPanel.getWidth()/2 - width/2,leftFillProgressJPanel.getHeight()/2 - height/2, width, height));
```